# An error message occurred during the installation of Elasticsearch in mac m2

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

This is the code that occurs when you run it without touching anything after installation using brew tap elastic/tap and brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full .

```
#####name#####@#####name#####-ui-MacBookAir ~ % brew services start elasticsearch-full
Warning: Calling plist_options is deprecated! Use service.require_root instead.
Please report this issue to the elastic/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/elastic/homebrew-tap/Formula/elasticsearch-full.rb:68

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/#####name#####/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch-full.plist` exited with 5.
```

Afterwards, when restarting through brew services restart elasticsearch-full, the following code appears, but it is not executed, and a message that the jdk is damaged is output on the MacBook.

```
rew services restart elasticsearch-full  
Warning: Calling plist_options is deprecated! Use service.require_root instead.
Please report this issue to the elastic/tap tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/elastic/homebrew-tap/Formula/elasticsearch-full.rb:68

Stopping `elasticsearch-full`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `elasticsearch-full` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearc
==> Successfully started `elasticsearch-full` (label: homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearc
```

If you enter elasticsearch without using the brew command, it will run. I'm wondering if this is a normal run, why is this happening, and how to fix it.

The version of elasticsearch is 7.17.4 and java is using openjdk 1.8.0_292.

I tried reinstalling elasticsearch, reinstalling brew, and even rebooting, but nothing worked.

Comment: where you able to fix it? I have the same issue

Comment: Facing the same issue, is this issue fixed?